# Conditions in nginx configuration allow directive not working

Tags: nginx-config

Good day. Not strong in setting up nginx, so I would like to ask for help. I have the following settings in nginx:

```
``
set $allow_ip 192.168.0.100;
if ($arg_cat = newin) {
    set $allow_ip 0.0.0.0/0;
}

location ~ /api.php {
   try_files     $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
  include       fastcgi_params;
  allow $allow_ip;
  deny all;
``
```

I need to give access to the api.php file only to a specific address (for example, 192.168.0.100), but if the **cat** parameter in the request is equal to **newin**, then access to it must be given to everyone. With the way that I try, I get the error **`invalid parameter "$allow_ip" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf`**.

As I understand it, variables are not supported in the allow directive. I've tried different options, but none work. Please help me to make the correct config